# Freeware online store?

Tags: gratis, web-apps, ebooks, shopping-cart

I need a freeware program to create an online store for e-books conforming to the following requirements:

- PayPal support
- OK with just a few items (currently I have about one or two ebooks)
- Easy to make custom design landing pages
- AdWords and Facebook conversions tracking
- Automatic delivering bought files to the buyer

Note that I am myself a professional programmer and can create it for myself, but to use existing software I would spend less time to set and configure it than programming myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welll, paypal buy buttons do a bunch of what you want. This is closest to free because:

- Simple html web site (use the most basic hosting that works for you)
- paypal account has transaction fees, but no monthly fee

To run a real store/cart, you need a hosting plan that supports a real ecommerce system. For example, a bluehost account with zencart or magento support. Look for a hosting plan that has cpanel support to set up one of these systems with one click. The "ware" part of this is free (zencart and magento are foss), but the hosting will cost whatever the hosting costs.

The main foss carts are:

- magento
- opencart
- prestashop
- zencart
- oscommerce

Comment: Does Magento support delivering to the buyer several temporary (say, 2 days) download links?

Comment: @porton If the links are dynamically genned, you may need to use a plugin or write a plugin. But there is a huge magento community to help you here.

Comment: @AngeloFuchs expanded!